# How to integrate UML diagrams into GitLab or GitHub

Tags: git, github, uml, markdown, gitlab

I want to publish some programming documentation I have in a public available repository. This documentation has formatted text, some UML diagrams, and a lot of code examples. I think that GitHub or GitLab are good places to publish this.

To publish the UML diagrams, I would like to have some easy way to keep them updated into the repository and visible as images in the wiki. I don't want to keep the diagrams in my computer (or on the cloud), edit them, generate an image, and then publish it every time.

Is there a way to put the diagrams in the repository (in PlantUML syntax would be ideal), link them in the markdown text, and make the images auto-update every time the diagram is updated?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

### Edit: Alternative with Proxy service

This way is significantly different and simpler than the answer below; it uses the [PlantUML proxy service](http://plantuml.com/server.html):

```
http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?cache=no&src=https://raw.github.com/plantuml/plantuml-server/master/src/main/webapp/resource/test2diagrams.txt
```

The GitHub markdown for this would be:

```
![alternative text](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?cache=no&src=https://raw.github.com/plantuml/plantuml-server/master/src/main/webapp/resource/test2diagrams.txt)
```

<del>This method suffers from not being able to specify the SVG format (it defaults to PNG)</del>, and <del>it is perhaps not possible to work-around the caching bug mentioned in the comments</del>.

---

After trying [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32209044/1168342), I discovered the service to be slow and seemingly not up to the latest version of PlantUML.

I've found a different way that's not quite as straightforward, but it works via  PlantUML.com's server (in the cloud). As such, it should work **anywhere you can hotlink to an image**.

It exploits [the `!includeurl` function](http://plantuml.com/preprocessing.html) and is essentially an indirection. The markdown file links to a PlantUML source that includes the diagram's source. This method allows modifying the source in GitHub, and any images in the GitHub markdown files will automatically update. But it requires a tricky step to create the URL to the indirection.

[image: Diagram of how it works]

1. Get the URL to the raw PlantUML source, e.g., `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-china/plantuml-gist/master/src/main/uml/plantuml_gist.puml` (using the example in the joanq's answer)
2. Go to http://plantuml.com/plantuml/form (or PlantText.com) and create a one-line PlantUML source that uses the `!includeurl URL-TO-RAW-PLANTUML-SOURCE-ON-GITHUB` operation. Continuing with the example URL, the PlantUML (meta)source is:

   ```
   !includeurl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-china/plantuml-gist/master/src/main/uml/plantuml_gist.puml
   ```
3. Copy the image URL from PlantUML.com's image, e.g., http://plantuml.com:80/plantuml/png/FSfB2e0m303Hg-W1RFPUHceiDf36aWzwVEl6tOEPcGGvZXBAKtNljW9eljD9NcCFAugNU15FU3LWadWMh2GPEcVnQBoSP0ujcnS5KnmaWH7-O_kEr8TU and paste it into your GitHub markdown file. This URL won't change.

   ```
   ![PlantUML model](http://plantuml.com:80/plantuml/png/3SNB4K8n2030LhI0XBlTy0YQpF394D2nUztBtfUHrE0AkStCVHu0WP_-MZdhgiD1RicMdLpXMJCK3TC3o2iEDwHSxvNVjWNDE43nv3zt731SSLbJ7onzbyeF)
   ```

**Bonus**: You can even get access to the SVG format by modifying the `plantuml/png/` part of the URL to be `plantuml/svg/` as follows

```
![PlantUML model](http://plantuml.com:80/plantuml/svg/3SNB4K8n2030LhI0XBlTy0YQpF394D2nUztBtfUHrE0AkStCVHu0WP_-MZdhgiD1RicMdLpXMJCK3TC3o2iEDwHSxvNVjWNDE43nv3zt731SSLbJ7onzbyeF)
```

#### Example on GitHub

https://github.com/fuhrmanator/course-activity-planner/blob/master/ooad/overview.md

### Caveat with private repos

As [davidbak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751579/davidbak) pointed out in a comment, the raw file in a private repo will have a URL with `token=<LONGSTRINGHERE>` in it, and this token changes as the source file updates. Unfortunately, the markdown breaks when this happens, so you have to update the Readme file *after* you commit the file to GitHub, which is not a great solution.

Comment: I'm not sure it's perfect, because GitHub caches images from `.md` files in its camo.githubusercontent.com site. I currently have a use-case diagram I updated, but the updates didn't get to the `.md` file after several days, even when I updated other parts of the `.md` file. I may have to touch the parts that refer to the image. YMMV.

Comment: Indeed, GitHub seems to only update its cached `camo` site images when the URL changes to the image. A way to update the URL without actually changing it is to add/remove `.svg` (or `.png` if you're using that format). PlantUML doesn't care if you have that extension at the end, but GitHub will think you changed the URL and update its cache in `camo.`. See https://github.com/fuhrmanator/course-activity-planner/commit/45fd5d86153003092593cd028f3fded1eb60917c for details.

Comment: I don't think that GitLab is caching images the same way, so there shouldn't be a problem in my case, but it's good to know how to solve it just in case.

Comment: to avoid caching just add some parameter to the url
e.g.
http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?src=https://raw.github.com/plantuml/plantuml-server/master/src/main/webapp/resource/test2diagrams.txt?ttt=1
and
increment it each time the uml file(test2diagrams.txt) is modified

Comment: To avoid caching `cache=no` url parameter should be added: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?cache=no&src=https://raw.github.com/plantuml/plantuml-server/master/src/main/webapp/resource/test2diagrams.txt

Comment: @hal The caching problem is with GitHub and not PlantUML, so I'm not sure how that cache flag helps.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator, caching problem is always browser issue, not GitHub or PlantUML. When you use `cache=no` url parameter, PlantUML server will set `Cache-Control: no-cache` header, so browser will not put the image to cache. When you press F5 in browser, new request for the image will be made to PlantUML server. If you pass github url to master branch as `src` (not specific comment), then PlantUML will request latest version of file and will return updated image.

Comment: is there a way to make this for for private repos too?

Comment: "Alternative with Proxy Service" works great.  The way to get it to work with private repos is to include the `?token=<LONGSTRINGHERE>` as part of the raw url.  Unfortunately, that token changes with every edit of the plantuml source, so you have to work a bit to keep the markdown doc up-to-date.  But it is doable.

Comment: @hal OK - I updated the answer for the `cache=no` feature. It's important to note that it does take some time for the image to update when the plantuml source is changed. I found some hints at https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview/issues/207#issuecomment-261716706

Comment: @MartinDürrmeier If you want to avoid manual handling of the token, consider checking my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75919567/4425335, having faced the same issues I created a simple fast CLI tool to handle the previews that you can integrate into your local/CI workflow, I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 16):

This is an old question, but it comes up early in the searches for solutions to this problem.

**UPDATE**

GitLab now support both [Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io) and PlantUML diagrams on their public offering. Mermaid is supported out of the box.

````
```mermaid
sequenceDiagram
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
Alice -> Bob:Another authentication Response
Bob --> Alice: Another authentication Response
```
````

[Example](https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#/edit/eyJjb2RlIjoic2VxdWVuY2VEaWFncmFtXG5BbGljZSAtPiBCb2I6IEF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uIFJlcXVlc3RcbkJvYiAtLT4gQWxpY2U6IEF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uIFJlc3BvbnNlXG5BbGljZSAtPiBCb2I6QW5vdGhlciBhdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiBSZXNwb25zZVxuQm9iIC0tPiBBbGljZTogQW5vdGhlciBhdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiBSZXNwb25zZSIsIm1lcm1haWQiOnsidGhlbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0In19)

**Orig Answer**

The other answers discuss GitHub, but it is worth noting that GitLab has native integration for this, if you are deploying in-house. For some reason, they have never activated the feature on their public offering. There are [tickets open](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/infrastructure/issues/2163) to activate the feature.

If you are working of an in-house hosted solution, there are instructions available in the [administration documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/integration/plantuml.html)

Basically you

1. stand up your own plantuml server
2. check the `Enable PlantUml` in GitLab server configuration
3. write PlantUml in your markdown

````
```plantuml
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
   
Alice -> Bob: Another authentication Request
Alice <-- Bob: Another authentication Response
```
````

Comment: gitlab.com supports plantuml now, and test fine. Please to 
ref  [gitlab-plantuml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/readiness/blob/master/plantuml/overview.md)

Comment: @Jesse I almost consider that irrelevant given Mermaid support, but plantUML still covers more use cases. Either way, good to hear.

Answer (score 10):

I found it is possible to do this using plantuml-gist on http://uml.mvnsearch.org/

Just put a valid puml file in the repository and include a link to this site in the documentation.

For example, for the file https://github.com/linux-china/plantuml-gist/blob/master/src/main/uml/plantuml_gist.puml in GitHub, you would use http://uml.mvnsearch.org/github/linux-china/plantuml-gist/blob/master/src/main/uml/plantuml_gist.puml as your link.

Here's what it looks like linked in StackOverflow:

[UML image http://uml.mvnsearch.org/github/linux-china/plantuml-gist/blob/master/src/main/uml/plantuml_gist.puml](http://uml.mvnsearch.org/github/linux-china/plantuml-gist/blob/master/src/main/uml/plantuml_gist.puml)

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with GitLab. I always get a "No PUML file found", even though I have checked the path several times.

**EDIT**: server at *uml.mvnsearch.org* seems down.

Comment: This would be even cooler if you showed an example in gollum wiki markup, but it's good enough to figure it out.

Comment: It appears the server that uml.mvnsearch.org is using doesn't grok the latest PlantUML language. I posted an answer that uses PlantUML.com's cloud server.

Comment: @joanq emedded image link possibly broken

Answer (score 4):

**For Gitlab**
Step 1: To enable the PlantUML and insert the PlantUML server location
[image]
Step 2: To create a PlantUML example and then you will see the result on the preview

```
@startuml
Bob -> Alice : hello
@enduml
```

[image]

**For GitHub**
Step 1: To create a PlantUML file
[image]

```
@startuml
Bob -> Alice : hello
@enduml
```

Step 2: Get a URL from raw
in my example: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/williehao/nginx-certbot/main/nginx-certbot.iuml"
[image]
[image]
Step 3:  Integrate PlantUML render engine with GitHub markdown
[image]

```
![your-UML-diagram-name](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?cache=no&src=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/williehao/nginx-certbot/main/nginx-certbot.iuml)
```

PS: replace your own raw URL from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/williehao/nginx-certbot/main/nginx-certbot.iuml" to ****

[image]

[reference](https://github.com/jonashackt/plantuml-markdown)

Answer (score 3):

Since GitLab supports rendering PlantUML out of the box, you can use the following:

**README.md**

````
This is some example text in a Markdown file. Followed by a PlantUML diagram, loaded from an URL.

```plantuml
!include https://gitlab.com/my-drawing.puml
```
````

When you 'preview' the file, it will render the text together with an image of the PlantUML diagram.

For more information about PlantUMLs `!include` directive, see https://plantuml.com/preprocessing#393335a6fd28a804

Answer (score 3):

> To publish the UML diagrams, I would like to have some easy way to keep them updated into the repository and visible as images in the wiki

This should be possible on GitHub now (Aug. 2022)

> ### [Wikis now support math and Mermaid diagrams](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-09-wikis-now-support-math-and-mermaid-diagrams/)
>
> [Earlier this year (Feb. 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71118868/6309), GitHub added support for LaTeX style mathematical expressions and Mermaid diagrams in Markdown.
>
> However, until now, GitHub wikis were missing this support.
> **You can now use these formatting features in GitHub wikis**.
>
> For more information about using mathematical expressions and Mermaid with GitHub, see [creating diagrams](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-diagrams) and [writing mathematical expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/writing-mathematical-expressions) in the GitHub documentation.

Those diagrams includes [ULM ones](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/classDiagram).

[image: UML]

Answer (score 2):

Good news regarding GitHub!

Just found out, that for **Github - Mermamid graphs are nativly supported now** within GitHub Issues, GitHub Discussions, pull requests, wikis, and Markdown files.

Just put your graph definition to your Markdown file.

````
Here is a simple flow chart:

```mermaid
graph TD;
    A-->B;
    A-->C;
    B-->D;
    C-->D;
```
````

- [Flow chart example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChRGZ.jpg)
- See https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-diagrams for details.
- Here you find a working example https://gist.github.com/dirksan28/b270aacc5eb07a0c7b1bc75f5fbd24e3 on GitHub

Comment: But I did mention that support [6 month ago in this same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73300843/6309).

Comment: @C You're right - did not see / recognize your post between all those poml-for-markdown posts. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

**GitLab**

Already support PlantUML natively as mentioned in other posts.

**GitHub**

I wish they support it natively too, but they don't at the moment.

**Workaround**

I built my own workaround similar to the PlantUML proxy mentioned above, but a little bit better.

**TLDR**:

- Example: https://puml-demo.herokuapp.com/github/ghe/lyang/puml-demo/blob/master/README.md
- Source Code: https://github.com/lyang/puml

**Long**:

- It supports arbitrary urls
- It supports both public and private repos on https://github.com
- It supports GitHub Enterprise instances
- It does not expose API tokens as part of the URL like the PlantUML proxy solution
- It can be used outside of GitHub, e.g. in emails, wiki, presentation etc.
- Private repos and GHE instances needs your own `puml` app with API token configured.
- Examples can be found in https://github.com/lyang/puml

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my OSS project you are welcome to try: [plantaznik](https://github.com/grissius/plantaznik), it is a Rust CLI tool for inlining PlantUML links. You can install it via [cargo](https://crates.io/crates/plantaznik) (`cargo install plantaznik`) or download prebuild libraries in [releases](https://github.com/grissius/plantaznik/releases).

[image]

Just place the following macros to your README:

```
<!-- plantaznik:./path/to/plantuml/source.plantuml -->
![](???)
```

And run:

```
$ plantaznik README.md
```

You can easily use it for multiple files, in your git hooks or CI. See readme for more examples.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my open source project that handles all this for you https://github.com/danielyaa5/puml-for-markdown

[image]

### How It Works

#### Using PlantUML Web Service to Render PUML Diagrams

You can use PlantUML using the online web service to generate images on-the-fly. A online demonstration is available at http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml. You can pass the encoded text of your diagrams to the web service in the url path and it will generate an SVG or PNG for you. Here's a simple HelloWorld example http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/Aov9B2hXil98pSd9LoZFByf9iUOgBial0000. Large diagrams will have very long encoding strings, they can exceed maximum url length. They also don't look very good in markdown files. By default the CLI will use the tinyurl.com service to shorten the link to the diagram.

#### Encoding PUML Diagrams for the Web Service

The CLI will use the plantuml-encoder package to encode puml files. To support hyperlinking diagrams we need to parse all hyperlinks in the puml files. A dependency graph is created for the files and a DFS is performed where we create links for the leaf nodes first, then replace the links in the parent nodes with the links to the leaf nodes. The puml files are not actually modified, only the puml files content in memory is modified. By default the tinyurl free service is used to shorten the links.

In order to support !include we parse puml files and replace any !include with the contents of the file referenced.

#### Parsing Markdown

The markdown files are then parsed for markdown comments. If the comments reference a PlantUML file, a link to the web service url will be added next to the comment. Because these links contain the full PlantUML diagram encoding in it, there are no issues using them in private repositories.