# How to make GitHub Pages Markdown support mermaid diagram?

Tags: javascript, jekyll, github-pages, mermaid

I am hoping to use mermaid in GitHub-pages, with simple commit and push.

In other words, I am hoping to wirte in my markdown file like this

````
```mermaid
graph LR
   A --> B
   A -->C
   C -->D
```
````

and add some js on my _layouts/post.html to somehow transform this to a mermaid graph.

I have found this [theme](https://github.com/kitian616/jekyll-TeXt-theme) claims that it supports such thing. But this theme looks way too heavy for me, the js were just too much, so I thought I could only use this [file](https://github.com/kitian616/jekyll-TeXt-theme/blob/master/_includes/markdown-enhancements/mermaid.html), which is simply

```
<script>
 window.Lazyload.js('{{ _sources.mermaid }}', function() {
   mermaid.initialize({
     startOnLoad: true
   });
   mermaid.init(undefined, '.language-mermaid');
 });
</script>
```

In my _include/mermaid.html, I replaced `{{ _sources.mermaid }}` to the mermaid cdn

```
<script>
 window.Lazyload.js('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.0.0/mermaid.min.js', function() {
   mermaid.initialize({
     startOnLoad: true
   });
   mermaid.init(undefined, '.language-mermaid');
 });
</script>
```

it still won't work. In my post, it was shown as regular code blocks, not a mermaid diagram.

Edit: In chrome developer's view, I don't see any connections made to the link `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.0.0/mermaid.min.js`.

And I tried this code, a connection to mermaid wes made in `network` tag in developer view, but the mermaid diagram still doesn't work

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.0.0/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
    startOnReady:true,
    theme: 'forest',
    flowchart:{
            useMaxWidth:false,
            htmlLabels:true
        }
};
mermaid.initialize(config);
mermaid.init(undefined, '.language-mermaid');
</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.0.0/mermaid.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  
<body>
 <pre><code class="language-mermaid">graph LR
A--&gt;B
</code></pre>

<div class="mermaid">graph LR
A--&gt;B
</div>
 
</body>
<script>
var config = {
    startOnLoad:true,
    theme: 'forest',
    flowchart:{
            useMaxWidth:false,
            htmlLabels:true
        }
};
mermaid.initialize(config);
window.mermaid.init(undefined, document.querySelectorAll('.language-mermaid'));
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: how do you run html codes on github, i dont think that is possible?

Comment: You can render your GitHub hosted Markdown files as HTML pages using GitHub Pages (https://pages.github.com/), which is what the original question was about. You can add custom JavaScript, CSS, HTML etc.

Comment: For GitHub, see: [Include diagrams in your Markdown files with Mermaid](https://github.blog/2022-02-14-include-diagrams-markdown-files-mermaid/) and [mermaid-js's README](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid#readme).

Comment: @wooohooo's solution works well and requires minimal configuration setup.
Notice for default Github Pages, it actually uses a theme: https://github.com/pages-themes/primer.
All you need is to copy and create **_layouts/default.html** and put in the two corresponding `<script>` sections. The `<pre><code class="language-mermaid"></code></pre>` part is handled automatically by Github Pages action.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it buy installing Github Mermaid extensioin in the browser.
Actually, they have support for Chrome, Opera & Firefox.

I am using Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-%20-mermaid/goiiopgdnkogdbjmncgedmgpoajilohe?hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Feb. 2022: Markdown pages support Mermaid ([gist too](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-28-gists-now-support-mermaid-diagrams/)) (aug. 2022: [wiki pages too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73300843/6309)).
As [Jegors Čemisovs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12278291/jegors-%C4%8Cemisovs) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883747/how-to-make-github-pages-markdown-support-mermaid-diagram/71118868#comment125751536_71118868), this does not apply yet to GitHub pages, as illustrated by his [example site](https://rabestro.github.io/test-mermaid/).

See:

> ### [Include diagrams in your Markdown files with Mermaid](https://github.blog/2022-02-14-include-diagrams-markdown-files-mermaid/)
>
> [Mermaid](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid#readme) is a JavaScript based diagramming and charting tool that takes Markdown-inspired text definitions and creates diagrams dynamically in the browser. Maintained by **[Knut Sveidqvist](https://github.com/knsv)**, it supports a bunch of different common diagram types for software projects, including flowcharts, UML, Git graphs, user journey diagrams, and even the dreaded Gantt chart.
>
> Working with Knut and also the wider community at **[CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/)**, we’ve rolled out a change that will allow you to create graphs inline using [Mermaid syntax](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/n00b-syntaxReference?id=syntax-structure):
>
> [image: Example]

Comment: GitHub shows it in README.md file but doesn’t show on generated GitHub pages. The test repository: github.com/rabestro/test-mermaid

The generated GitHub pages site: https://rabestro.github.io/test-mermaid/

Comment: @JegorsČemisovs Good point. I hope they will extend the support to GitHub generated pages.

Comment: @JegorsČemisovs I have included your caveat in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer that mention the plugins. In a firm I work form asked to provide extention links to most supported browsers.

Here are the Mermaid extention that renders Mermaid on browser level, I have tested them all:

Mermaid diagram for documentation
When you use mermaid to create diagrams in Gitlab, and in case the business moves with new Version Control provider like Github or Azure DevOps or others, in this case you need to install a browser plugins to make it possible to view the diagrams.

- [Chrome -> GitHub + Mermaid](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-%20-mermaid/goiiopgdnkogdbjmncgedmgpoajilohe?hl=en)
- [Firefox -> GitHub + Mermaid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-mermaid/)
- [Opera -> Extensions for Mermaid](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/extensions-for-mermaid/)
- [Edge -> Extensions for Mermaid](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/extensions-for-mermaid/deifijioejcfbfhaedeimiinfgigmhln)

Answer (score 1):

I assume this requirement is with `Jekyll + Github Pages` since Github Pages is mentioned.

There's plugins doing this, such as [jekyll-spaceship](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship#4-mermaid-usage).
It supports a lot more rendering format.

In order to make the [unsafe plugins](https://pages.github.com/versions/) works on Github Pages, you will need a Github Workflow Action [jekyll-deploy-action](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-deploy-action).

BTW: The custom plugins (putting plugins in your _plugins folder) won't work with Github Pages, they are not the `safe plugins`. Github Pages locks the config to `safe=true`, even locally.

Comment: On June 2, 2022, I was able to work around this stupid "unsafe plugins" problem by using Netlify to host the rendered site *instead* of GitHub Pages...

Answer (score 0):

The URL you tried to use does not exist. This is a correct URL:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.0.0/mermaid.min.js

Comment: sorry, I updated the link but the result is still not right.

Comment: @waterliu is the code inside the function executing at all?

Comment: sorry I have no idea what that means... I have little knowledge about js. I can only say that this is all the js in my post. No other <script> tags.

Comment: @waterliu insert a command of debugger; as the first operation of the function of the code you have given. Open the dev tools of your browser and load your page. If the code inside the function is executed, then your code should jump right into it. In the dev tools in the Sources tab check your Javascript. Is it refreshed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185611/discussion-between-water-liu-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and ended up just going with a custom jekyll plugin. If you are able to use custom plugins, the following will replace the markdown code blocks for mermaid with  elements.

````
Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :pre_render do |post, payload|
  docExt = post.extname.tr('.', '')
  # only process if we deal with a markdown file
  if payload['site']['markdown_ext'].include? docExt
    newContent = post.content.gsub(/```mermaid([^`]+?)```/, '<div class="mermaid">\1</div>')
    post.content = newContent
  end
end
````

Answer (score 0):

i've opted to use html instead of markdown language. Using examples from wooohooo, Mermaid's site, and stackoverflow

header html in my post.md

enclose your mermaid code inside div tags with mermaid class attribute

```
sequenceDiagram
    participant Alice
    participant Bob
    Alice->>John: Hello John, how are you?
    loop Healthcheck
        John->>John: Fight against hypochondria
    end
    Note right of John: Rational thoughts 
prevail...
    John-->>Alice: Great!
    John->>Bob: How about you?
    Bob-->>John: Jolly good!
```

in the header of the default layout template

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/10.6.1/mermaid.min.js"></script>
```

after html body of the default layout template

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
           var config = {
                startOnLoad:true,
                htmlLabels:true,
                callback:function(id){
                    console.log(id,' rendered');
                },
                flowchart:{
                        useMaxWidth:false,
                    }
            };
            
            mermaid.initialize(config);
        },false);
```

Answer (score -3):

The new best answer is that GitHub now directly supports including diagrams in your markdown files with Mermaid!

https://github.blog/2022-02-14-include-diagrams-markdown-files-mermaid/

Comment: Yes, that is what I mention in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71118868/6309)

Comment: GitHub shows it in README.md file but doesn’t show on generated GitHub pages. The test repository: https://github.com/rabestro/test-mermaid