# Why mermaid graph not appear in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, markdown, mermaid

I create markdown text as tutorial says, bu ti is not rendered, but text is shown, what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Note: this is [supported in GitHub only in Feb. 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71118868/6309). Maybe it will be supported in GitLab as well soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in [github/markup/issue 533](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/533), while this is not yet supported in GitHub, it should be supported in GitLab (since [GitLab 10.3](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/3711), Sept. 2017)

As seen in [gitlab-foss issue 3711](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/3711#note_52037197), you might need to refresh the cache for the rendered graph to show up.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117144/why-mermaid-graph-not-appear-in-gitlab/59124460#comment104477656_59124460) by the [OP János](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239219/j%C3%A1nos), the format needs to be respected, and no extra whitespace (in each row) should be present.

Comment: Maybe refresh cache, but I think **removing empty white space in each row** what really helped me

Comment: @János Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: What threw me off was that it wouldn't show the chart properly in Preview.  Once I committed it, it displayed properly.  But thanks for the tip about the white space!