# About anonymized image URLs in GitHUB

Tags: image, github, url, markdown, plantuml

Working on how to present *UML* diagrams written in plain text with *PlantUML*, and to be able to visualize them correctly from a *Markdown* file, I have found an interesting way to display the diagram and the text, but a problem has arisen.

I correctly make the diagram correctly in the markdown file, as follows:

1. I insert an `img` tag that points to the PlantUML Service to generate the image, passing as a parameter raw file in github and the ordinal of the diagram to be displayed within the document.
2. I wrap the PlantUML code in a `section` tag with its corresponding `sumaryze` to show/hide in code.

When I push the document, everything is updated, normal, but the image generated at https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ is not updated.

I have tried clearing the cache as indicated in [About anonymized image URLs in GitHUB](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/about-anonymized-image-urls) but have not gotten any satisfactory results. It must be said that it does not matter from which browser or computer is working.

Here, I leave you the [examples](https://github.com/srlopez/RUP/tree/main/examples), click on each one to see them. The most simple [README.md](https://github.com/srlopez/Pruebas/blob/master/README.md)

Here I present an example of how I have worked with markdown (I have changed some quotes inside `code`, necessary so that `markdown` into `code` is admitted in this question);

```html
<img src = "http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?src=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srlopez/RUP/master/examples/fraccion_completo.md&idx=0" alt = "" / >

<details><summary>Code #0</summary>

'''plantuml
@startuml
:User: as u
rectangle system {
  (Add 2 Fractions\nUC#1) as add
}
u - add
@enduml
'''
</details>
```

You can do the test in a `README.md` of a local project.
Include the code that I have indicated, changing the quotes, push README.md, then locally change the code again and push.

You can see that everything has been updated, opening the `section` tag, but the image remains the same.

This is a README.md example https://github.com/srlopez/Pruebas/blob/master/README.md
[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771815/1168342 you can use `cache=no`  in the URL, e.g.,

```markdown
<img src = "http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/proxy?cache=no&src=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srlopez/RUP/master/examples/fraccion_completo.md&idx=0" alt = "" />
```