# Rendering PlantUML from Azure DevOps Repo in Confluence

Tags: git, azure, confluence, plantuml

For a project I'm working on I'd like to adopt the [C4 diagramming language](https://c4model.com/) to illustrate technical designs. In order to manage changes to the designs I'd like to use [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/) so that I can express the diagrams as text which can be tracked in a Git repo (Azure DevOps).

The diagrams will appear in a Confluence wiki, but I don't want to manually render and upload the diagrams to Confluence because they will quickly become out of date. My research suggests that the best way around this is to use a PlantUML proxy server which you make a call to, providing the link to the PlantUML (.puml) file in Git as a parameter.

[image]

It's easy enough to spin up the PlantUML server in Azure as a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/plantuml/plantuml-server), but it seems pretty complicated to manage the authentication between it, Confluence, and the git repo. I've seen that there is also a [Confluence plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211675/git-for-confluence-markdown-plantuml-graphviz-mermaid?tab=overview&hosting=cloud) available but I wanted to check with the community whether this is the easiest solution or whether there's anything else that I haven't considered?

Comment: The easiest is to render things via PlantUML.com, but obviously it's not private. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771815/1168342

Comment: Git itself won't be aware of any of this. You'll use Git in the usual way, whatever that may be.

Comment: Thanks @Fuhrmanator, in that example they're using Github which provides a handy link to the raw files that can be used in the request to the PlantUML proxy. In Azure devops its not as simple, so it's discussion on that here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-link-to-raw-content-of-file-in-azure-devops

Comment: Yes I know @torek, that wasn't the question.

Comment: I was just telling you why the tag [tag:git] is inappropriate here.

Comment: It's not inappropriate because there would need to be some authentication with Git in order to retrieve the files.